# .live() vs .bind()

Tags: jquery, bind, live

I want to know the main difference between

`.live()` vs. `.bind()`

methods in jQuery.

Comment: You and a lot of other people too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937039/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bind-and-live-methods-in-jquery

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that since 1.7 (released after this question) `live()` is deprecated in favor of `on()`.

Comment: For an e.g. `$(document).on("click", "input#goodbye", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });` and dont pace it in $(document).ready(); keep it outside of it. at same level.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The main difference is that `live` will work also for the elements that will be created after the page has been loaded (i.e. by your javascript code), while `bind` will only bind event handlers for currently existing items.

```
// BIND example
$('div').bind('mouseover', doSomething);
// this new div WILL NOT HAVE mouseover event handler registered
$('<div/>').appendTo('div:last');

// LIVE example
$('div').live('mouseover', doSomething);
// this new appended div WILL HAVE mouseover event handler registered
$('<div/>').appendTo('div:last');
```

**Update:**

jQuery 1.7 deprecated `live()` method and 1.9 has removed it. If you want to achieve the same functionality with 1.9+ you need to use a new method `on()` which has slightly different syntax as it's invoked on document object and the selector is passed as a parameter. Therefor the code from above converted to this new way of binding events will look like this:

```
// ON example
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div', doSomething);
// this new appended div WILL HAVE mouseover event handler registered
$('<div/>').appendTo('div:last');
```

Comment: As per comment from andyzinsser: As of v1.7, .live, .bind, and .delegate have all been replaced by .on.

Answer (score 27):

I did a statistical analysis of `.bind()` vs `.live()` vs `.delegate()` using FF profiler. I did 10 rounds of each (not a sufficient sample to be definitive, but illustrates the point). These are the results.

1) Single static element with an id using the click event:

```
.bind():     Mean = 1.139ms, Variance = 0.1276ms
.live():     Mean = 1.344ms, Variance = 0.2403ms
.delegate(): Mean = 1.290ms, Variance = 0.4417ms
```

2) Multiple static elements with a common class using the click event:

```
.bind():     Mean = 1.089ms, Variance = 0.1202ms
.live():     Mean = 1.559ms, Variance = 0.1777ms
.delegate(): Mean = 1.397ms, Variance = 0.3146ms
```

3) Multiple dynamic elements (first button creates second...) using the click event:

```
.bind():     Mean = 2.4205ms, Variance = 0.7736ms
.live():     Mean = 2.3667ms, Variance = 0.7667ms
.delegate(): Mean = 2.1901ms, Variance = 0.2838ms
```

Interpret how you wish, but it seems to me that as dynamic elements increase on a page, .delegate() seems to have the best performance while static elements perform best with .bind().

Keep in mind that I am using a very simple click event triggering an alert. Different pages, with different environments (ie. CPU, multi-tab browsing, running threads, etc) will render differing results. I used this as a basic guideline for my decision to use one or the other. Please advise if you have come up with a different result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You should consider to use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()` whereever possible.
Since event delegation for `.live()` always targets the body/document and you're able to limit
"bubbling" with `.delegate()`.

See http://api.jquery.com

**UPDATE**

From [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method. 
>   For earlier versions, however, `.delegate()` remains the most effective means to use event delegation.

Comment: See my comment below, but I must generally agree. If the tree structure of a page is unknown (and you don't want to bind an event to `<body>`) .live() may be a better catch-all, but I see that being more the exception than the rule.

Comment: it appears that from jquery 1.7 onward, the preferred method to use is .on()

Answer (score 11):

As of v1.7, .live, .bind, and .delegate have all been replaced by `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

I was curious of the diffence myself, so I wrote up an article with some code examples.
http://blog.tivix.com/2012/06/29/jquery-event-binding-methods/.

Sounds like depending upon how you call .on(), jquery will mimic .bind, .live, or .delegate. This gives your event handlers a more elegant implementation.

Comment: the given link is dead. For those interested in migrating your code: https://web.archive.org/web/20121004004902/http://blog.tivix.com/2012/06/29/jquery-event-binding-methods/