# Jquery live() vs delegate()

Tags: jquery, live

I've read some posts here and elsewhere on the web about the differences between `live()` and `delegate()`. However I haven't found the answer I'm looking for (if this is a dupe please tell me).

I know that the difference between `live` and `delegate` is that `live` cannot be used in a chain. I also read somewhere that `delegate` is in some cases faster (better performance).

My question is, is there a situation where you should use `live` instead of `delegate`?

**UPDATE**

I've set up a [simple test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on) to see the difference in performance.

I've also added the new `.on()` which is available in jQuery 1.7+

The results pretty much sum up the performance issues as stated in the answers.

- Don't use `.live()` unless your jQuery version doesn't support `.delegate()`.
- Don't use `.delegate()` unless your jQuery version doesn't support `.on()`.

The difference between `.live()` and `.delegate()` is A LOT bigger than between `delegate()` and `.on()`.

Comment: I took the liberty of summarising this excellent post and other useful comments in one place, for my own record and in case this anyone else finds it useful. [**JQuery live vs delegate vs bind**](http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2011/oct/jquery_live_vs_delegate)

Comment: As of version 1.7, `.live()` is gone. You will find the new `.on()` method instead.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I never use `live`; I consider the benefits of using `delegate` to be so substantial as to be overwhelming.

The one benefit of `live` is that its syntax is very close to that of `bind`:

```
$('a.myClass').live('click', function() { ... });
```

`delegate`, however, uses a slightly more verbose syntax:

```
$('#containerElement').delegate('a.myClass', 'click', function() { ... });
```

This, however, seems to me to be much more explicit about what is actually happening.  You don't realise from the `live` example that the events are actually being captured on `document`; with `delegate`, it is clear that the event capturing happens on `#containerElement`.  You can do the same thing with `live`, but the syntax becomes increasingly horrid.

Specifying a context for your events to be captured also improves performance.  With the `live` example, every single click on the entire document has to be compared with the selector `a.myClass` to see if it matches.  With `delegate`, that is only the elements within `#containerElement`.  This will obviously improve performance.

Finally, `live` requires that your browser looks for `a.myClass` **whether or not it currently exists**.  `delegate` only looks for the elements when the events are triggered, giving a further performance advantage.

---

NB `delegate` uses `live` behind the scenes, so you can do anything with `live` that you can do with `delegate`.  My answer deals with them as they are commonly used.

Note also that neither `live` nor `delegate` is the best way to do event delegation in modern jQuery. The new syntax (as of jQuery 1.7) is with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. The syntax is as follows:

```
$('#containerElement').on('click', 'a.myClass', function() { ... });
```

Comment: +1. The re-use of a preceding selector in `live()` is confusing, leading to user misunderstanding of what it's actually doing. `delegate()` is clearer. Also, though `delegate()` is (currently) implemented using `live()`, it's using a four-argument version of `live()` that isn't documented, so presumably for internal use only. Personally I'd always avoid `live()` unless I needed to run on jQuery 1.3 for some reason (hopefully not).

Comment: @all: From the jQuery docs: `As of jQuery 1.4, live events can be bound to a DOM element "context" rather than to the default document root.` Wouldn't `live()` be better to use now since we can add the event context. Since `delegate()` calls `live()` internally. So I think 1 call less. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Great answer. Really great. However, I still prefer live. unless my application is one huge monstrous js app, the simplicity of live is greater than the performance gain. Moreover, since I will usually be using bind (or one of it's shorter versions), the closeness is great. Still a really great answer. Made me actaully get the difference. +1.

Comment: @PeeHaa I think you're right about that, but as mentioned before you, using delegate makes things easier to read.

Comment: @trusktr actually I couldn't be more wrong. See my updated question for a perf test.

Comment: is this a new kind of war, event propagation approach holy war?

Answer (score 24):

They are exactly the same except:

- `.delegate()` lets you narrow down the a local section of the page, while `.live()` must process events in the entire page.
- `.live()` starts with a wasted DOM selection

When you call `.delegate()`, it just turns around and calls `.live()`, but passes the extra *context* parameter.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L948-950

As such, I'd always use `.delegate()`. If you really need for it to process all events on the page, then just give it the `body` as the context.

```
$(document.body).delegate('.someClass', 'click', function() {
    // run handler
});
```

<s>Older versions of jQuery actually have `delegate` functionality. You just need to pass a selector or element as the context property when calling `.live()`. Of course, it needs to be loaded on the page.</s>

```
$('.someClass', '#someContainer').live('click',function() {
    // run handler
});
```

And you have the same behavior as `.delegate()`.

Comment: I don't know why this answer doesn't have more votes. `.delegate()` uses `.live()`. Performance-wise, `.delegate()` clearly outperforms `.live()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind/7692651#7692651

Comment: agree .live is much slower.

Answer (score 3):

Two situations come to mind:

1. You would be using `delegate` on the `body` element, so then you can just use `live` instead as it's simpler.
2. You need to use an older version of the jQuery library, where the `delegate` event is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example

```
<ul id="items">  
   <li> Click Me </li>  
</ul>

$('#items').delegate('li', 'click', function() {  
    $(this).parent().append('<li>New Element</li>');  
});
```

By passing a DOM element as the context of our selector, we can make  Live() behave (almost) the same way that delegate() does. It attaches the handler to the context, not the document - which is the default context. The code below is equivalent to the delegate() version shown above.

```
$("li", $("#items")[0]).live("click", function() {  
    $(this).parent().append("<li>New Element</li>");  
});
```

[Resource](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/)

But, you'd better use delegate for better performance [see here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on)