# jQuery append, not exactly available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

When i've loaded a page, you'll be able to upload some photos. The images that i've uploaded is then appended (using .append) to a list-element. How can i assign my JS code to make those images clickable?

I've tried with  $('img').click() etc but since the images is added after the DOM is ready i dont think they exactly is available.. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was made for this:

```
$('img').live('click', function() {
      // code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the jQuery `.live()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> The .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants. The handler passed to
>   .live() is never bound to an element;
>   instead, .live() binds a special
>   handler to the root of the DOM tree.

Alternatively, you can check out [the jQuery `.delegate()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and read this StackOverflow response on the differences between `.live()` and `.delegate()`...

[Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4579154#4579154)

I hope this helps.