# Any way to trigger the handler added later?

Tags: jquery, live

```
$('.kkk').click(function() {
  // Execute Event
});

$('body').append('<div class="kkk">Another target</div>');
```

Since it was added after the call to .click(), clicks on it will do nothing.

A>  I wonder if Any way to trigger the handler(click) added later?
    except live()

Thank you~~~~

Comment: Why not `live`? That would be how you should handle this.

Comment: live *is* the tool for the job.  Is there a problem with it?

Comment: i'm studing on live but hard to understand about event bubbling

Comment: `live` is incredibly easy to use... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) is exactly what you need for this. [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) should be deprecated, in my opinion.

```
$("body").delegate(".kkk", "click", function() {

    // Execute Event

});
```

**EDIT :** Seeing as how there's some discussion over live() vs delegate(), take a look at the posted answer to this question: [Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate).  I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: delegate and live serve slightly different purposes...  There's room and use cases to support having both in jQuery.

Comment: Delegate() is much, much more efficient than live().

Comment: Not when you're binding to the body.  It would be more efficient if you were using it in the context of some much deeper element.

Comment: I agree. That would be the OP's job to narrow it down.  I don't know their markup.

Comment: Thank you! Scott. I did it. this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Also, don't forget to change `$("body")` to something more narrowed down.  For example if all of your `".kkk"` classes are in a div, you could use `$("div")` or if they are all inside of a div with `id="content"`, you could use `$("#content", "div")`. Basically, try to use the most narrowed down selector you can to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.kkk').live('click',function() {
  // Execute Event
});

$('body').append('<div class="kkk">Another target</div>');
```

using `live` will match all future elements written to the page as well as those that exist when the event is "bound".

**UPDATE:**

jQuery as of 1.7 has deprecated `live` (and `bind`) in favour of using `on` with delegated events.  To use a delegated event, you attach `on` to an element that will exist on the page at load, then filter by a selector that will exist later.  For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '.kkk', function(){
    // Execute Event
});

$('body').append('<div class="kkk">Another target</div>');
```

If the element will exist on the page when document `onload` is fired, you can simply attach it as:

```
$('body .kkk').on('click', function(){
    // Execute Event
});
```