# Cannot control content added dynamically with .load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have content that I'm loading using an AJAX call and displaying the HTML (consisting of `div`s, etc) inside of a `ul` parent.

Now I've written a series of `.click` and `.hover` functions that work perfectly on everything, right up to where my content is dynamically loaded, and then don't work at all on the dynamically-loaded content.

I've gone through all my `div` ids to make sure they are correct and they are. Is there a way to gain control over the AJAX-loaded material?

Comment: you need to assign .click or .hover to does elements after they are created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code run only with the elements that existed at that time and no the "future" elements. You have 2 choices:

1) Re-run your "onload" javascript code (that was applied on document ready) after you load your ajax content.

2) Use `.live()` instead of `.bind()`:
So change

```
$('#selector').bind('click', function(){..
```

To

```
$('#selector').live('click',function(){..
```

The difference is that `live` uses the elements that match the selector **now and in the future**, versus `bind` uses the elements that match the selector only at the time it's called.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your event handlers are bound to elements that exist at the time that they are set.

Either re-attach the handlers to the new, dynamically-created material, or make use of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/); these "attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future".

Answer (score -1):

You should either rebind the events after the content is loaded or use

`.delegate` ([api](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) to have the event attached automatically to newly loaded elements.

something like:

```
$("ul#container").delegate("li", "hover", function(){
    doStuff();
});
$("ul#container").delegate("li", "click", function(){
    doOtherStuff();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('a#whatever').click(function(){....
```

To

```
$('a#whatever').live('click',function(){....
```

Comment: `live` is inferior to `delegate` and should probably not be advised: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate

Comment: live is not the same as delegate. they each have their own optimal usage.

Comment: I agree that live has its usages. In this case its not.