# Using AJAX to change months in a PHP calendar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP built calendar that displays dates for each month. Now what I want to do is to be able to navigate between months without having to refresh the page.

Normally, the script takes parameters in the URL so I tried to pass that information through the AJAX load request. It works for one month forwards and one month backwards. However after that, the link stops working and the "#" goes back into the URL.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Calendar "next"
$("#db-cal-next").click(function(){     
    var get_params = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#db-calendar-wrap").load("../template/db-calendar.php", get_params);
    return false;
});

//Calendar "previous"
$("#db-cal-prev").click(function(){
    var get_params = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#db-calendar-wrap").load("../template/db-calendar.php", get_params);
    return false;
});
});
```

I had the PHP script pass on the required parameters needed to create a request for the next and previous months and had it pass that information through the "rel" attribute. I think the problem lies with the fact that the rel attribute isn't changing when the calendar script runs so a new set of parameters aren't generated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `#db-cal-next` and `#db-cal-prev` are inside of `#db-calendar-wrap`, than, when you loading HTML via AJAX to wrapper, new elements with ids "db-cal-next" and "db-cal-prev" created. SO, new elements are not in your jQuery set. You need to use jQuery `.live()` event binder function: http://api.jquery.com/live/
But, may be functionality of [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline) is all you need?

Comment: Would everyone quit using `live()` already?  They made `delegate()` for a reason.

Comment: I didn`t know about this. Thanks for the information, `delegate()` is a good way to do this too

Comment: @Peter, `delegate()` seems to be more flexible and functional

Comment: Thank you! I used `delegate()` to bind the events and it works well!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate for why you should use delegate instead of live.

Answer (score 0):

If you want things to refresh on the client, then you really need a client-side solution.

There are lots of Javascript calendars available: both in toolkits, as well as standalone modules.  For example:

[CalendarView](http://calendarview.org/)

[jsDatePick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/)

[Dojo Widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/widget/Calendar.html)