# Why is the click event triggered multiple times in my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a search button which has a click event. When I click it the very first time, it triggers once as expected. When I click it a second time it trigger twice and when I click on it again it trigger multiple times... Any idea why this is occurring?

This is the code for click event:

```
$("#search_top_form").delegate("#search_button","click",function(e) {   
            wrapperConsole('click search');
                alert("event trigger");                                    
            submitSearchForm();

        });
```

Comment: wrapperConsole() and alert() is just for debugging purpose

Comment: can you please provide the associated html code too . i would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

my guess you are doing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/3756r/
meaning calling this delegate from submitSearchForm().

another potential problem i see here is if you are using an actual form and the button is a submit button, you have to pass event to the click function and call event.preventDefault() so the form won't submit

Comment: i visit your link and it is same in my case .. when i click in your code result that is click me .result is the same as it in my case mutiple trigger

Comment: exactly - showed you what i think you are doing. you should call delegate only once and not from the even handler

Answer (score 1):

before delegate, add this
undelegate("#search_button","click").delagate......

```
$("#search_top_form").undelegate("#search_button","click").delegate("#search_button","click",function(e) {   
            wrapperConsole('click search');
                alert("event trigger");                                    
            submitSearchForm();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you reload this script part on every click. This means delegate works for each load and cause to trigger so many times.

You may try

> $("#search_top_form").undelegate(...).delegate(..);

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert in jquery try this

```
$("#search_button").click(function(){ 
            wrapperConsole('click search');
                alert("event trigger");                                    
            submitSearchForm();
        });
```

Comment: This does look better to me... I'm not an expert either though

Comment: Regarding: `.click()` vs. `.delegate()`, see [To use delegate() or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029178/to-use-delegate-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use just something like that, why do u use delegate?

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```