# JQuery rebind after using html()

Tags: jquery, html

I am using JQuery .Html() to swap around the divs on my page using this code:

```
    $('#item1').html($('#item8').html());
    $('#item8').html('<p>sdsdsd</p>');
```

I've found that this works great, however the JQuery methods stop working. So div #item1 will have a toggle for example, it will work fine until I use .html().

Is there any solution to rebind the JQuery to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly are the event handlers bound to? Why don't you use DOM manipulation? `$('#item1').empty().append($('#item8').children());`? Don't use `.html()` as long as you don't have to.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I was just about to suggest that in an answer, although you'd probably want `contents()` rather than `children()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X63tG/ This seems to work fine....  Are you saying that you've bound to an element within your divs, or to the divs themselves?  Element inside of divs: use `live`.  Divs themselves? Should work fine.

Comment: @Andy: Ah yes... well, depends on the content(s) ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: of course :-) Just playing it safe!

Answer (score 4):

use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and it will work

Comment: Don't use live, use delegate instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting the HTML of the elements and then having the browser reparse it into another element, you could just move nodes from one container to another:

```
var $item8 = $('#item8');
$('#item1').empty().append($item8.contents());
$item8.html('<p>sdsdsd</p>');
```

This will keep any current bindings on the already created elements, so there's no need to use `live()` or rebind those events.

`live()`, or rather, `delegate()` is still a decent alternative solution, however.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.delegate` [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) See [Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate) as to why you should use `delegate` over `live`.

```
$('itemParent').delegate('#item8', 'click', function(){});
```