# Checkbox doesn't work in replaced content

Tags: javascript, jquery, uniform

So I'm having some weird behaviours in my code and I don't know why.

I'm using uniformjs so, for example a checkbox is like this:

```
<label>Check Boxes</label>
    <div class="input_group">
      <div class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="option" value="option 1" type="checkbox"></span></div>First option<br>
      <div class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="option" value="option 2" type="checkbox"></span></div>Second option<br>
      <div class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="option" value="option 3" type="checkbox"></span></div>Third option
    </div>
```

So, when the check option is checked the parent span add the class "checked".

So I was trying to develop a system in which an user is able to add an user and choose between creating a new address for that user or use the company one.

Both address are loaded in diferent divs and the company one get hidden so that's the function I made:

```
$('input[name="company_addr"]').change(function(){
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $('input[name="company_addr"]').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('checked',checked);
                if (checked)
                    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
                else
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
            });
            if (checked){
                newAddrContent = block_new.html();
                block_new.html(block_company.html());
            }
            else{
                block_new.html(newAddrContent);
            }
        });
```

If I delete the last if ... else and unhide the company address I see how both checks change so that part works flawlessly.

However the checkbox within block_new doesn't work anymore but the block_company one does. If I click on the company (which should be hidden) one the other one doesn't uncheck or check but the content is properly replaced.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally seems to be a bug with uniformjs commented here: github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/180

If anyone is interested in how I managed to solve this issue, I just changed the method to show, hide the proper divs so, when submitting the form I check which div is hidden and handle the form with this into account.

Answer (score 0):

You use check() which is one time function. You must bind a live event with .live(event, function) in order for the handler to work on the future elements.

So simply instead of:

```
$(elements).change();
```

use

```
$(elements).live('change', function() {
...
});
```

Comment: This worked for once more time. I click, it shows the Company Address, click again shows again the fields to be filled but the checkbox it's still checked (wrong) and now I can't use it anymore...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you create a new `input` on the fly the `change` event is not being rebound. You can fix this by using `.delegate` [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('.input_group').delegate('input[name="company_addr"]', 'change', function(){
             //do your stuff
});
```

[Reasons to use delegate over live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

Comment: What should input parents be?

Comment: in your case it would be `input_group` just changed my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't change anything I mean, the behaviour it's still the same. I'm using uniformjs to style the elements may be for that? I've tried to call $.uniform.update(); too but seems not to solve anything it's like the element loose all it's functionallity once it's changed

Comment: Finally seems to be a bug with uniformjs check here -> https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/180 What should I do with the answer?

Comment: Up to you, you dont have to accept any, you can actually add what you found out as an answer to your own question and accept it.