# event is fired multiple times for dynamically created DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

The program has two javascript functions to generate a table (`generateTable`) and delete one selected row (`deleteOneRow`).

`generateTable` function generates a table based on server data. Each row is in the following format:

```
<tr><td><span class="desc">aaa</span><a href="#delete_choice" class="delete-choice">Delete</a></td> </tr>
```

Basically, each row is some text followed by a 'delete' link.
When the script finish the table generation, it calls `$(".delete-choice").click(deleteOneRow)` to bind click to the event handler.

In the event handler function `deleteOneRow`, it first simply deletes all the rows in the table. Then  call `generateTable` again to display the remaining data entries. Code structure is like follows:

```
function deleteOneRow() {
    var choiceIdx = ... //get index
    $(".delete-choice").unbind('click');
    CurrentChoices.splice(choiceIdx, 1); // remove the entry from the array
    $("#problem-choice-table  tr").each(function(){ // delete the DOM entries
        $(this).remove();
    })
    generateTable();    
}
```

If the table have two rows, after clicking the delete link in the 1st row, the first row was deleted. Then it generates a table with the 2nd row moving to the 1st. However, the `deleteOneRow` is called again, then the 2nd row is removed eventually.

I guess this is due to event is fired multiple times. I tried unbind, stopPropagation, etc. Nothing works.

Comment: Your posted html is invalid. Your table rows don't contain `td` cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) to attach an event is perfect for situations like this where content is added / removed dynamically and you want to match against the same selector, have you looked into using that?

Comment: `live` is deprecated for jQuery 1.7. They now recommend using `on` or `delegate.` Delegate is preferred method for jQuery 1.4.2+ (just learned this myself)

Comment: thanks mrtsherman, didn't realize the difference.  here's a good q&a about the topic I found illuminating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate

Comment: Using delegate indeed solves the problem. It is also more efficient. Thanks, guys.