# Create new div dynamically with jQuery and use it?

Tags: jquery, dom, html, click

I tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var conntent = $("#conntent");
    $('#form_post').submit(function(){
        if($("#set").val() != ''){
             $.post('post.php', $("#form_post").serialize(), function(data){
                 conntent.append('<div class="item"><span>' + data + 
                 '</span></div>');
             });
        }
        $("#set").val('');
        return false;
     });    

   //Then I try to click on new the new element

        $('span').click(function(){
            alert("OK");
        });
   });
```

However, after this I can't use click on the `spans`

I think is it possible after appending them that the are not part of the DOM.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: Also see [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you're using jQuery 1.7 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Is this code:

```
$('span').click(function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

running *before* this code:

```
conntent.append('<div class="item"><span>' +data + '</span></div>');
```

This is very much a possibility since the POST is asynchronous.

You can use [jQuery's `.live()` or `.delegate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate) to bind to elements which haven't been added to the DOM yet.  That way when they are dynamically added the click event will automatically bind to them.

Alternatively, if you just want that call to `.click(function())` to happen after the POST then you can call it in the response rather than outside of the whole thing.  Something like this:

```
$.post('post.php', $("#form_post").serialize(), function(data){
    conntent.append('<div class="item"><span>' +data + '</span></div>');
    $('span').click(function(){
        alert("OK");
    });
});
```

Personally I'd opt for the `.delegate()` approach, but the overall structure is up to you.  There may be cases in the life of that page which you *don't* want to bind, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe 2 possible reason cause it doesn't work
1st You're trying to bind event before 'span' is part of DOM
Solution is bind event after this:

```
conntent.append('<div class="item"><span>' +data + '</span></div>');
$('span:last').bind('click', handler);
```

2nd maybe you should use context like this

```
$('span', conntent).bind('click',handler)
```

cheers :)