# jquery each function syntax update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of info panels sharing the same class which I wish to show/hide using the slideToggle function. The content of the panel is pulled in dynamically through json. so Ibelevide I must use the 'live' and not 'bind' function? The following code will toggle all the panels simultaneously. I wish only one panel to toggle at a time.

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function() {
    $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: So just update your last question...

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: This is not the question I have answered. I see you changed your question after you solve your first issue. This is not the correct way to ask another question. I suggest revert this question to original version, accept one of your answer that solves your question and ask another question which refers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.sc-info').slideToggle();
```

You need to target the .sc-info that is relative to the toggle.

For example if your html looked like this:

```
<a href="#" class="sc-info-toggle">Toggle</a>
<div class="sc-info">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

You could use this:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });
```

If the toggle is inside of the content then use .parent() instead of .next().

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I tryed your suggestion but no joy. The html is <li <a href=​"#info" class=​"sc-info-toggle">​Info​</a>​</li><li class=​"sc-info">​....</li>

Comment: Try $(this).parent().next('.sc-info').slideToggle();

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks ridecar2 and everyone for their help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `.each()` because jQuery applies your function to matched elements by default and you have to put `return false;` where click event occures. So this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function(event) {
  $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning false from withing the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback, not from within the `.live()` callback:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').each(function(){ 
    $(this).live('click', function(event) {
        $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });         
});
```

According to the documentation, returning false from the `.each()` callback:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

And returning false from the `.live` callback basically cancels the default action of the underlying event.

And by the way, `.live()` is now deprecated and you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (in jQuery 1.7+) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

`live` is deprecated.  You want to use `on` instead

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.sc-info-toggle', function() {
    $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });
```

You haven't stated what the relationship is between the anchor that was clicked, and the panel you want to slide.  If the panel is right next to the anchor, this should work:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.sc-info-toggle', function() {
    $(this).next('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });
```

---

Ideally, try to identify some container—say, a div with id of `foo`—which will always contain all of these anchors, and select on *that* instead of `document`.

```
 $("#foo").on('click', 'a.sc-info-toggle', function() {
    $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });
```

This will potentially be more efficient since you won't be listening to every single click that happens on your document, but just the ones that happen inside of `foo`.

Comment: You'll also want to prevent default on the anchor click rather than return false. They'll both work, but one is a better practice than the other.

Comment: @GregPettit - are you sure?  I thought returning false from a jQuery handler *was* the standard way to prevent default.

Comment: @AdamRackis I really should keep a couple of source links to back up my claims, so no I can't say I'm 100% sure. Certainly a lot of examples in the wild and on jQuery's own site have `return false`, but this is more out of habit than good practice. My understanding is that returning false will allow the event to bubble (before returning false at the end). Preventing default will stop the event from even bubbling, giving a performance benefit. Plus, I just find it more elegant: `event.preventDefault()` is certainly explicit. ;-) Just have to pass the event into the function.

Comment: @Greg - you've [got it backwards](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) :) - return false does both, preventDefault only prevents the default action.  (To stop bubbling without return false you'd also have to call `stopPropagation()` or set `cancelBubble = true` for IE)

Comment: @AdamRackis I like CSS-Tricks, but Chris Coyier is not a reliable authority on JS. And the article HE links to didn't help me much. ;-) But since I wasn't 100% sure to begin with and you've raised some doubts, I'll definitely do some more research before making the same recommendation. I can say for a certainty that I've seen articles recommending e.preventDefault() and have seen other SO users recommend it. But I can't say with honesty anymore that my confidence isn't shaken. ;-)

Comment: @Greg - well preventDefault is the standard way of preventing the default action.  No question there.  And it'll still work with jQuery—it's standard after all.  But jQuery gives you the option of returning false to do *this*, and also prevent bubbling.  Here's a link to a blog by T.J. Crowder, one of the top JS people on SO  http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html

Comment: @AdamRackis going to get my conversation warning... ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false -- it only does both in jQuery. Also, if you use e.preventDefault() at the beginning of a function, you are guaranteeing prevention of the event regardless of errors in the handler. So there are reasons to prefer it (or not!), but I was wrong about the bubbling and performance gains.

Comment: @Greg - threads only get flagged after 20 comments, and this is at 8 and almost over since I essentially agree with you.  If bubbling is not a concern (and it seldom is) and you're worried about errors in your handler, then preventDefault as the first line is probably a **good idea**.  If you do care about bubbling, *and you're using jQuery*, then returning false is probably a good idea.  Canceling bubbling in a cross browser way is a huge pain (stopPropagation doesn't work on old ie).  The highly rated answer in that Q seems to agree with what I wrote above, doesn't it?

Comment: @AdamRackis Yup, it seems to. I have that pleasant feeling of having improved my knowledge... thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Happy New year,
Dude, why are you using each loop it's really not needed,  make it simle as follow:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function(event) {

// $(this) will return the link which is clicked

    $(this).find('.sc-info').slideToggle();
       return false;

  });
```

Comment: Hi thanks, if I do as you say every panel with the class .sc-info toggles simultaneously. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

the command `return false;` will only quit the `.each` loop.
Also, inside the `.live` you slideToggle ALL of the .sc-info's on that page, instead of just the one that relates to the button you clicked on.

```
  $('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function(event) {
    $(**the.div.you.need**).slideToggle()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

live binds event handlers to elements matching a selector, whether they exist now or in the future.  So using each here is kind of silly.  This does the same:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function(event) {
    $('.sc-info').slideToggle()
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `each()`, jQuery will handle that as the selector will return an array, also `return false` should be within the `live()` callback:

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function() {
    $('.sc-info').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

However if you're using the latest version of jQuery (1.7+) use the `.on()` method. Else I'd recommend using `.delegate()` if possible as its more efficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579154/978306

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it depends what your HTML looks like but at the moment you are targeting all elements with the class `.sc-info` rather than just the one near your toggle link.

It should look something like this (again, depending on your markup):

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().find('.sc-info').slideToggle();
});
```

This would find the panel in a structure like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="sc-info-toggle">Toggle 1</a>
    <div class="sc-info">Panel 1</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="sc-info-toggle">Toggle 2</a>
    <div class="sc-info">Panel 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (i guessed the handle is a child of the slide element):

```
$('a.sc-info-toggle').live('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.sc-info').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```