# How do I properly capture an onchange or onkeyup event for a dynamically inserted 'input' text element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

I have a bit of JavaScript that builds some HTML for me and inserts it into a `div`. I am using **jQuery 1.7.2** for this test.

I'm interested in attaching a custom change or keyup event handler on an `input` text field called `gene_autocomplete_field`.

Here's what I have tried so far.

The following function builds the HTML, which is inserted into a `div` called `gene_container`:

```
function buildGeneContainerHTML(count, arr) {
    var html = "";
    // ...
    html += "<input type='text' size='20' value='' id='gene_autocomplete_field' name='gene_autocomplete_field' placeholder='Enter gene name...' /><br/>";
    // ...
    return html;
}

// ...
$('#gene_container').html( buildGeneContainerHTML(count, geneNameArr) );
```

In my calling HTML, I grab the `gene_autocomplete_field` from the `gene_container` element, and then I override the `keyup` event handler for `gene_autocomplete_field`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#gene_container input:[name=gene_autocomplete_field]").live('keyup', function(event) {
            refreshGenePicker($("#gene_container input:[name=gene_autocomplete_field]").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I change the text in `gene_autocomplete_field`, the `refreshGenePicker()` function just sends an alert:

```
function refreshGenePicker(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

**Result**

If I type any letter into the `gene_autocomplete_field` element, the event handler seems to call `alert(val)` an infinite number of times. I get one alert after another and the browser gets taken over by the dialog boxes. The value returned is correct, but I worry that `refreshGenePicker()` gets called over and over again. This is not correct behavior, I don't think.

**Questions**

- How do I properly capture the `keyup` event once, so that I only handle a content change to the autocomplete field the one time?
- Is there a different event I should use for this purpose?

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that more than just a `keyCode` of 13 (Return/Enter) can be an issue — pressing Control, Alt, Esc or other special characters will trigger an event (but will be asymptomatic, as far as the infinite loop issue goes). The gene names I am filtering on do not have metacharacters in them. So I made use of an [alphanumeric detection test](http://inmyexperience.com/2004/01/detecting-alphanumeric-charact.html) to filter out non-alphanumeric characters from further event handling, which includes the Return key:

```
if (!alphaNumericCheck(event.keyCode)) return;
```

Comment: it seems .live is depreciated in favor of .on http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Do you mind posting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alert` is called infinite times because you use the 'Enter' key to confirm/dismiss the alert. Use `.on('change')` instead. This will prevent `refreshGenePicker` from being called when you use enter in an `alert`.

- [JSFiddle demonstration using `keyup`](http://jsfiddle.net/uqwAA/) (Click on OK to prevent infinite alerts).
- [JSFiddle demonstration using `change`](http://jsfiddle.net/uqwAA/1/)

However, the `'change'` event will only trigger if the input element looses focus. If you want to use `refreshGenePicker` on every key, use the following approach instead:

```
$("#gene_container input:[name=gene_autocomplete_field]").live('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) // filter ENTER
        return;
    refreshGenePicker($("#gene_container input:[name=gene_autocomplete_field]").val());
});
```

This will filter any incoming enter keyup events ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqwAA/2/)). Also switch to `.on` and drop `.live`.

**EDIT**: Note that there are more possibilities to dismiss an `alert` modal, such as the `escape` or `space` key. You should add a check inside your `refreshGenePicker` whether the value has actually *changed*.

Comment: Hmmmz On what browser is that return capture on the textfield? Cannot reproduce it on Chrome.

Comment: I am testing both Safari 5.1.5 and Chrome 18.0.1025.142.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 20 maybe that's it. Thanks! But I still think it's odd behavior, but hey what you gonna do :)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: Firefox and Opera on Windows are behaving the same. Internet Explorer 9 doesn't care about it, but it's a little bit slow (I can type asdfghj before the event gets fired). The joys of event propagation in interrupting JavaScript methods (`prompt`, `confirm`, `alert`) :).

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - Just updated your fiddle and reproduced in Chrome.

Comment: @Zeta - Nice catch! How incredibly stupid, though.  The keypress for the dialog is not a keypress event for the target field, obviously. Is there anywhere in the DOM where this gets distinguished?

Comment: @Anthony: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture - however, a modal dialog gets canceled by a `keydown`, it doesn't wait for a keyup signal. Try it for yourself in the first demo, just keep enter/esc/space pressed.

Comment: @Zeta - I saw it, I just am dumbfounded. So because the keyup is left lingering, the field is technically back in focus and thus catching it?  Since most of us stray from `alert` unless we're testing, is this something that has implications outside of this scenario?

Comment: @Anthony huh? In my Chrome is still works as expected. Without infinite alerts. I say Yay! for latest Chrome?

Comment: @Zeta - Actually, what this reminds me of is the auto-complete feature in browsers (specifically Chrome) where you have to press Enter (as opposed to right arrow or tab) to get it to select that choice, even though hitting enter inside a form is a habit everyone has learned to break, having submitted too many forms before their time. This is the exact opposite but just as counter-intuitive.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - Well I'm on Chrome 18, the latest non-dev/nightly, so maybe this has been addressed?  Do they have a decent Update log we can check? I'd love to see if they actually acknowledge the issue (or maybe it's a newer WebKit fix?)

Answer (score 1):

You should really use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using jQuery > 1.7.

Check out [the perftest](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on).

And also check out my some what [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate).

Also when testing equal you should really add [quotes around it](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
input:[name='gene_autocomplete_field']
```

---

To answer you real question :). It shouldn;t behave like that with the code you have presented. Maybe something else is wrong. Can you setup a jsfiddle with the issue?

Check out [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/PGu4k/) and perhaps you see what's wrong with your code:

```
function refreshGenePicker(value) {
    console.log('keyup! Value is now: ' + value);
}

(function($) {
    var someHtml = '<input type="text" name="gene_autocomplete_field">';
    $('body').append(someHtml);

    $('body').on('keyup', 'input[name="gene_autocomplete_field"]', function(e) {
        refreshGenePicker($(this).val());
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').html('<input id="text" />');
    $('#text').keyup(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

This works just fine. Since you've got our second code block in `<script>` tags, you might be running it more than once - which would cause it to bind more than once and produce more than one alert each time it is bound. You could of course use `.unbind()` on that input before adding the keyup, but I think a much better solution would be to group all the code in a single `$(document).ready();` to ensure you're only binding the object once.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7Ty/2/

Comment: No, this does not work on dynamically-inserted HTML. This would only work if the `input` element already exists.