# How to highlight content in HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have create link on same page . the content of this page is in the bottom and the anchor tab is on the top.

I would like to highlight the content area for 5 seconds when someone clicks on the top link (ancho).

Comment: Could you be more descriptive with your problem? What do you mean by "content" is it an element, or just text inside an element?

Comment: show us what you have so far. Paste some relevant code

Comment: Highlight as in selecting the text or what?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at jQuery and the Effects-Plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Comment: @little big rot and Roko C.buljan i mean text inside an element

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in very many ways, for example binding onHashChange and then changing background color:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $(".highlight").css("background","#AFA");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".highlight").css("background","transparent");
    },5000);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8kBj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give each piece of content a unique id as follows:

```
<div id="content_1"> ... </div>
```

Then use jQuery to set up events for each link:

```
$("div").delegate("#content_1", "click", function() {
  $('div.content_1').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Or you could use .on() or .live() but you get the idea.

Comment: Better to use `.on()` and to [not use `.live()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate).

Answer (score 0):

use `delay()`

```
$('#id-of-anchor').click(function(){

 $("#your-div").css('background','red').delay(5000).css('background','transparent');
 return false;    

});
```