# Rails2: RJS - Javascript events are not working when on page updates remotely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I am using RJS in my current project.

I have table rows with data and the last column contains a button, that binds javascript `click` function.

Now I have to do a AJAX and append newly created row to the table. It works fine. Here is the `create.rjs` template file.

```
page.insert_html(:bottom, "products", :partial => "product_row.html.erb", :locals => {:product => @product})
```

JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("button.add_color").click(function(){
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

Everything works fine except the javascript `click` event is not working for newly created row.

Please help on how to keep bind the javascript events for newly added DOM by AJAX?

Comment: @dimakura - Added JS code. I cannot give the real code but the basic code is that only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use jQuery's `.delegate` [method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('body').delegate('button.add_color', click, function(){
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

From `delegate`'s documentation:

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the *future*, based on a specific set of root elements.

Comment: I also found it working using `live` from [here](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/10/jquery-on-avoid-losing-event-binding-for-ajaxed-contents.html). I am not sure what is the efficient one.

Comment: @VenkatCh here's a good discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate you might find it useful