# The most strange issue i've seen: Jquery alert does not work and i don't know why

Tags: jquery, alert

i have a problem that i cannot solve by myself. 
Probably is the easier thing but i'm not able to find the problem in this code, so please give me a little help.

I need to do something on a .click event.

Jquery is included and the link works.
i have this code in my html file:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.contenutotesto').mouseover(function(){$(this).children("img").css( "opacity", "1" );});
jQuery('.contenutotesto').mouseout(function() {$(this).children("img").css( "opacity", "0.7" );});
$( "div" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
});
</script>
```

The crazy thing of this code is that the first 2 lines works, all other code will not. I try to put an alert before the 2 mouseover but it did not appear! Firebug does not find errors in console.

Can someone help me? thx.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?  `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: You probably should be using `$( "div" ).on( "click", function().....`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your jquery and use "on" instead of "live" to bind your event.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.contenutotesto').mouseover(function(){$(this).children("img").css( "opacity", "1" );});
jQuery('.contenutotesto').mouseout(function() {$(this).children("img").css( "opacity", "0.7" );});
$( "div" ).on( "click", function() {
 alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('elem').click(function(){
 alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
```

or

```
$(document).delegate('elem', 'click', function(){
  alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
```

or

```
$('elem').on('click', function(){
 alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
```

Do not use `.live()`, I also don't use it use `.delegate()` instead.

[Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

Check this out!