# Detect click event in any nested element of an specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I need to be able to detect any click that happens within a specific container referenced by class, if the user clicks on any of the nested elements I should be able to detect the click and update a flag

```
<div class="container" >
   <div class="x1">
   <div class="x2">
      <div class="">
         <span class="">
         <ul class="">
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried using jquery but I prefer to do it using backbone.

```
//$(document).on('click','.container', function(e){
//$('.container').delegate("div", "click", function(e) {
```

Not sure what event I need to use when the users are clicking in some of the nested elements within the div that have the container class. Basically, I need to update a flag in case of the user clicks outside of this div, but I don't want to have a large scope on the event handler that listens to the whole body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is DOM Event delegation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: Related: [Jquery live() vs delegate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4579117/3773011)

Comment: `"I need to update a flag in case of the user clicks outside of this div"` - How would that be accomplished by detecting clicks *inside* the `div`?  Can you elaborate on how your first attempt "didn't work"?  That would indeed detect clicks inside the `div`.

Comment: it seems some of the components have an event stop propagation that I was not aware of, so I don't receive the event in the next handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for a Backbone example, here's how to listen to clicks on a div and its children.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "my-test-view",
    template: '<div class="container"><div class="x1"><div class="x2">test</div></div></div>',
    events: {
        'click .container': 'onClick',
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template);
        return this;
    },

    onClick: function(e) {
        console.log("clicked on", e.target, " triggered from ", e.currentTarget);
    },
});

var view = new View();

$("body").append(view.render().el);
```

Clicking the `test` text should output:

```
clicked on <div class=​"x2">​test​</div>​  triggered from  <div class=​"container">​…​</div>​
```

With jQuery, the above is (roughly) the equivalent to:

```
$('.my-test-view').on('click', '.container', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked on", e.target, " triggered from ", e.currentTarget);
});
```

But for most case, this should be enough:

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked on", e.target, " triggered from ", e.currentTarget);
});
```

Don't use `.children().on(...)` as this will create a new listener for each child and it's inefficient.

Detecting a click outside a div is quite different and there are many ways to achieve it but none is perfect.

See :

- [Backbone view with **custom event to detect clicks outside** of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620475/1218980)
- [How to detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152975/1218980)
- [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1403615/1218980)

Personally, I used `focus` and `blur` events (don't forget `tabindex="-1"` on the element).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?:

```
$(document).on('click','.container *', function(e){
console.log(e.target);
});
```

The great thing about jQuery is that you can use the same selectors as you would use with CSS hence I used `.container *` to target all elements inside the container.

Answer (score -2):

I used the jquery .children() method. Check out [this code pen](http://codepen.io/itsmed/pen/JRrBYB).

```
var flag = 'whatever';

$(.container).children().on('click', function() {
  flag = 'updated';
});
```

Essentially, saying for all children of whatever element is class container (div in this case) add an event handler.

Comment: Using `.children().on(...)` like this is inefficient. Also, the `.container` should be a string.