# jquery bind vs live

Tags: bind, jquery

I am populating an element with some html:  table, checkboxes.
I have an onclick event in my checkbox, but the page doesn't seem to be listening to the click event.  I suspect it's because it was loaded after the javascript checkall() function got put into the DOM.

Here's what I have:

```
<select name="showcuslist" id="showcuslist">
  <option value="0">select a customer</option>
  <option value="1">John Smith</option>
  <option value="2">Jane Smith</option>
</select>

<div id="loadtables">---ajax loads stuff into here---</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("#showcuslist").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
     data:"formId=grabcusinfo&cusid="+$(this).val(),
     success:function(response){ eval(response); } 
   });
  });


});

function checkall(){
  $(".checkboxes").attr("checked",true);
}
</script>
```

Simply, when I get to this page I can select a customer from the dropdown menu.  Nothing too complicated.
Jquery then calls a page on the server for the purpose of grabbing some info about that customer.
The info is actually a list of Notes, so nothing huge.  But I format the notes into an html table.

The first column in that html table has checkboxes, corresponding to each Note record.
I also put a Master Checkbox in the top, so if I check that box, all boxes will be checked.

The html table loads fabulously, however, that master checkbox isn't working.

Here's the html table I load into the

```
<?php
    $alltables='<table>';
    $alltables.='<tr>';
      $alltables.='<th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" class="checkall" onclick="checkall();" /></th>';
      $alltables.='<th>Notes Title</th>';
    $alltables.='</tr>';

    $alltables.='<tr>';
      $alltables.='<td><input type="checkbox" id="someID" class="checkall" /></td>';
      $alltables.='<td>Notes Title Text...</td>';
    $alltables.='</tr>';
    $alltables.='</table>';

    $("#loadtables").html("'.addslashes($alltables).'");
?>
```

The checkall(); function works fine if I load the table when the page loads, but not when I load a new table with new data.

I've been told this is where live() or bind() helps out, but I'm honestly not understanding the jquery docs.

Comment: See some generic benchmarks

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind/7692651#7692651][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind/7692651#7692651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.bind()` will bind to an event for all matching DOM elements that exist **at the time that the bind function was called**.  Using `.live()` will bind to all matching DOM elements that exist at the time of the method call **and any matching DOM elements that get added dynamically in the future**.

So, if you are adding elements that you want to run some jQuery against, you should use `.live()` to automatically bind the event handler function to those elements as they are added.

Since you are writing out `<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" class="checkall" onclick="checkall();" />` as part of the table, I would modify your code to this:

1. remove the onclick attribute from the input element.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" class="checkall" />
   ```
2. add the click handler using the `live` function

   ```
   $(".checkall").live("click", function() { checkall(); });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`.bind()` sets an action listener for all matching elements *at the time of the function call*.

`.live()` will traverse the DOM tree and respond to all past and future matching elements at the time of the action. (IIRC)

I would expect `bind` to be more efficient, but `live` will better support adding/removing DOM elements.