# Can not control the item which create by appendTo function

Tags: jquery, appendto

I want to get the image url (the img in #demo) wich I parser from the JSON data and appendTo #demo.

I can see the picture which I get from flickr after parser the JSON data and appendTo to #demo.

But the "**$('#demo img').bind('click', function()**" never be trigger. So I can not get the img url and dump to #log to debug.

But If I write some static img elements into #demo , the click function can be triggered.

Is the "appendTo" cause it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Ch13_4_2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<script>
function onDeviceReady() {
   $('#shoot').bind('click', function() {
     $("#demo").empty();
      $("#log").empty();

      $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?&tags=baby&id=82216313@N00" ,
              function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

                var photoString = "<a href=\"#\"><img src=" + item.media.m + "></a>";                
                 $(photoString).appendTo("#demo");

                  if ( i == 3) return false;
                });
              });             
   });   
} 

function onLoad() { 
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">

<div data-role="page" id="home">   
   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
     <h1>Andy's Flickr Search</h1>
     <a href="#" id="shoot" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-inline="true">search</a>
   </div>


   <div data-role="content">
   <div id="log"></div>


     <div id="demo">

     </div> 

<script>

              $('#demo img').bind('click', function() {
                    $("#log").empty();
                    var img_link = this.src;                            
                    var photoString = "<img src=" + img_link + ">";                    
                    $('div #log').html(photoString);

           });  
</script>    


</div>   
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The magic word is delegation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated from one of static parents of the element, you can use `on` method.

```
$('#demo').on('click', 'img', function(){
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer. But if I change to your code , the function can not be trigger on static img or appendTo img.

Comment: @user1640586 Hi, you are welcome, the event will be triggered for both static and dynamic images.

Comment: @underfined, thanks for your answer ,after I change jquery to 1.8 and your .on method , it works .

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `bind` any more. As of 1.7, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the event handler.

```
$('#demo').on('click', 'img', function() {
   // ...
});
```

---

**Update:**

`live()` and `bind()` worked differently: `live()` will also work for non existent elements or elements that are created on the fly but `bind()` will only bind the event handlers for currently existing elements. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind)

`.delegate()` was used for event delegation, but `.on()` is improved version of it and will created for clean coding and combination of `bind()` and `delegate()`

Other good questions:

1. [jQuery: live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate)
2. [.delegate() vs .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on)
3. [Jquery live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

Comment: @adeneo: live -> delegate -> bind -> on   Is that so, I think

Comment: @Starx: I think both live as well as bind is deprecated now. and on is the answer.

Comment: @refhat, Yes, very true, avoid using `live()` and `bind()`. They will likely be removed on possible future version.